# Endless scrolling of recyclerview by fetching the data of api

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I have an api which contains 10 data per page , now i want to load the other 10 data of next page while i scroll down the recycler view but  i am having some issues while loading the next page data, next page data doesn't load,it would be great if I could get some help.
My EndlessScroll java code:

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
            else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
            // get maximum element within the list
            lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }
        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
        if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Call this method whenever performing new searches
    public void resetState() {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        this.loading = true;
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

}
```

My fragment where i want to use endless recycler view:

```
public class BlankFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public Session session;
    private RecyclerView categoryRecyclerView, property_recycler;
    private PropertyAdapter propertyAdapter;
    private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private Datum datum;
    private String next_page_url = null;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        property_recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.viewAllHotRc);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        property_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        property_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        property_recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
                if (next_page_url != null) {
                    getNextPageData(next_page_url);
                    next_page_url = null;
                }
            }

        };
        property_recycler.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

        session = new Session(getContext());
        Call<Datum> propertyCall = apiInterface.getAllProp(session.getAccessToken());
        propertyCall.enqueue(new Callback<Datum>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Datum> call, Response<Datum> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    datum = response.body();
                    final List<Property> propertyList = datum.getPropertyList();
                    propertyAdapter = new PropertyAdapter(propertyList, getContext());
                    property_recycler.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);

                    String pagingObject = datum.getNextPageUrl();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+pagingObject);

                    if (pagingObject != null) {
                        next_page_url = pagingObject;
                        Log.d(TAG, "NEXTPAGE: "+next_page_url);

                    } else if (pagingObject== null) {
                        next_page_url = null;
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Datum> call, Throwable t) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    void getNextPageData(String nextUrl) {

        Call<Datum> callNextPageData = apiInterface.getNxt(session.getAccessToken());
        callNextPageData.enqueue(new Callback<Datum>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Datum> call, Response<Datum> response) {
                datum = response.body();
                final List<Property> propertyList = datum.getPropertyList();
                propertyAdapter = new PropertyAdapter(propertyList, getContext());
                property_recycler.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);

                String pagingObject = datum.getNextPageUrl();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+pagingObject);

                    if (pagingObject== null) {
//                        getNextPageData(pagingObject.getString("next"));
                        next_page_url = pagingObject;
                    } else if (pagingObject == null) {
                        next_page_url = null;
                    }



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Datum> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

My Api Modle:

```
public class Datum {

    @SerializedName("current_page")
    @Expose
    private int currentPage;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Property> propertyList = null;
    @SerializedName("first_page_url")
    @Expose
    private String firstPageUrl;
    @SerializedName("from")
    @Expose
    private int from;
    @SerializedName("next_page_url")
    @Expose
    private String nextPageUrl;
    @SerializedName("path")
    @Expose
    private String path;
    @SerializedName("per_page")
    @Expose
    private int perPage;
    @SerializedName("prev_page_url")
    @Expose
    private String prevPageUrl;
    @SerializedName("to")
    @Expose
    private int to;

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    public List<Property> getPropertyList() {
        return propertyList;
    }

    public void setPropertyList(List<Property> propertyList) {
        this.propertyList = propertyList;
    }

    public String getFirstPageUrl() {
        return firstPageUrl;
    }

    public void setFirstPageUrl(String firstPageUrl) {
        this.firstPageUrl = firstPageUrl;
    }

    public int getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(int from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getNextPageUrl() {
        return nextPageUrl;
    }

    public void setNextPageUrl(String nextPageUrl) {
        this.nextPageUrl = nextPageUrl;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public int getPerPage() {
        return perPage;
    }

    public void setPerPage(int perPage) {
        this.perPage = perPage;
    }

    public String getPrevPageUrl() {
        return prevPageUrl;
    }

    public void setPrevPageUrl(String prevPageUrl) {
        this.prevPageUrl = prevPageUrl;
    }
```

My Interface:

@GET("/api/properties")
Call getAllProp(@Header("Authorization") String token);

@GET("/api/properties")
Call getNxt(@Header("Authorization") String token);

Comment: `i am having some issues with it` and now we should guess which issue you have, right? is there any prize for the one who guesses correctly?

Comment: no it didnot work

Comment: i want to load the data from page 2 from api while i scroll (at page 1 there are only 10 data , so now i want to load the data from rest of the pages)